# What MySQL type is most suitable for "price" column?

Tags: mysql

I have a `price` column in `products` table.

I wonder which MySQL type is the most suitable for this column. Is it `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT`, or something else ?

The price can be for example: `139.99`, `40`, `14.5` (2 digits after the decimal point, like in shops).

Please advise.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

DECIMAL beacuse decimal value is stored precisely. E.g. DECIMAL(10, 2) will suit perfectly for prices not higher than 99999999,99. [MySQL Docs reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)

Comment: Although decimal is more appropriate, integer will perform better.
Just multiply the amount by 100 and store the value in cents.

Comment: what about greater than your number?

Comment: I use DECIMAL(10, 2): 123,33.00 and format number_format($price, 0 , '.', ',') now show 123,33 on form edit and save data second it only 123.

Comment: I'd like to upvote but I won't, how the current score matches the answer is too magnificent.

Answer (score 18):

Field type "Decimal" will work best. Like:

```
`product_price` decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL,
```

It will store a price up to `999999.99`

If you have high prices then you can use

```
`product_price` decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL,
```

i.e. up to `9999999999.99`

Answer (score 7):

You should certainly use a decimal type for money. Never floating point, contrary to other answers. And using varchar prevents you doing calculations.