# Storing double values in Mysql | Decimals or Not

Tags: mysql

I'm storing some double values on mysql table for products' price.

Column type is : **double**

Length is :8

Decimal is : **2**

Is it valid or useful? Also If I set decimals to "0" I can still store decimals. Which approach is better?

Also default, when I pass values to mysql, decimal seperator is comma ",". (PHP pass doubles like 123.45 so on php side seperator is point "." How can I enforce to "." on mysql side)? As far as I know it is a SQL standart so I can't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397302/what-mysql-type-is-most-suitable-for-price-column

Comment: Decimal/money (fixed-precision) is the only correct way to store money. It's just convenience that money is ever used with more traditional relative-precision types. The `,` issue sounds like localization; it doesn't apply wrt. SQL if using placeholders in PHP.

Comment: There is a close request for question. But alternative solution link's answer doesn't explain "why it should like it".

Comment: I'm living in Turkey and decimal seperator is not comma(,), it is point(.). So money operations related with it.